# Simple Oracle stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have this SQL query:

```
select title
from DEPARTMENT;
```

I tried to write a stored procedure:

```
create PROCEDURE select_some
(whats VARCHAR2 ,c_select_some OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) 
AS 
BEGIN 
OPEN c_select_some FOR
SELECT whats
FROM department;
END select_some;
/
```

But where I execute it with "title" parameter I got 8 rows with 'title' instead actual content. What's wrong?

Execution:

```
var whats varchar2(20)
variable whats = 'Title'
variable mycursor refcursor;

exec select_some (:whats, mycursor);
```

Comment: `SELECT whats` =  `SELECT 'Title'`, because procedure's `whats` parameter is being given `Title` argument (`variable whats = 'Title'`) that's why there will be returned as many rows with value `Title` as many rows in the `department` table. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? If you wanna pass column name dynamically you should look toward dynamic SQL

Comment: just
 select some_param
from DEPARTMENT; 
that will be return 8 rows, I just want parameterized sql queries

Comment: That's not what "parameterized sql queries" means. What you want is "dynamic SQL", as suggested previously.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this, you need to use dynamic SQL.

Something like this

```
create or replace procedure select_from_department(
  col_name in varchar2,
  c_res      out sys_refcursor
) 
is
  l_sql varchar2(300);
begin
  l_sql := 'select ' || dbms_assert.simple_sql_name(col_name) || ' from departments';
  open c_res for l_sql ;
end;
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d8d6315143cbac0361358e11567fe31f)

Comment: plus one for using `dbms_assert.simple_sql_name` and not simple pasting `col_name` in the query string.